# If ... Else statement seems to be returning the wrong output

Tags: java, if-statement

I am just exploring different methods to test out Log class in java, where I use Log.d() if a certain text view is shown and Log.e() to log an exception error if otherwise.

However, the logcat seems to be showing the opposite output instead. Why is that so?

My main activity code:

```
package com.example.dummy_app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (findViewById(R.id.editText).toString().equals("Happy Birthday!")) {
            Log.d("logMessage", "correct message shown");
        } else {
            Log.e("logMessage", "exception error");
        }
    }
}
```

XML --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Happy Birthday!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The logcat is showing "exception error" instead of "correct message shown". I have also tried removing the `toString()` but it still shows the same result. Can anyone explain why?
[image]

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? This looks like a perfect opportunity. Simply check what `findViewById(R.id.editText).toString()` actually returns.

Comment: thanks for the guidance @Amongalen! Good point. I tried debug by using  Log.e("logMessage", findViewById(R.id.editText).toString()); in the else statement instead. The logcat shows logMessage as androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{506d7be V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f070035 app:id/editText}. That explains why it's not equals to "Happy birthday!"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the following statement,

```
findViewById(R.id.editText).toString().equals("Happy Birthday!")
```

Don't declare [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) like that. It is not a good practice. First, declare your TextView as follows,

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Now you can finally do whatever you want with it like getting input as follows,

```
String inputTxt = textView.getText().toString();
```

So your full code should be like the following,

```
package com.example.dummy_app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if (textView.getText().toString().equals("Happy Birthday!")) {
            Log.d("logMessage", "correct message shown");
        } else {
            Log.e("logMessage", "exception error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hasitha! Just something I noticed  EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); The object should be TextView --- i.e. editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); Otherwise the app will crash.

Comment: @unacorn Ops! My bad. I will update the answer. I read only the `edittext` variable in your `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
findViewById(R.id.editText).toString().equals("Happy Birthday!")
```

to:

```
findViewById(R.id.editText).text.toString().equals("Happy Birthday!")
```